# JavaScript - Check if at least one variable is true

Tags: javascript, variables, boolean

How do I check if at least 1 out of a group of variables is true.
For example:

```
var v1 = false;
var v2 = false;
var v3 = false;
var v4 = false;
var v5 = false;
```

Let's say that I have 5 buttons and the variable of `v1` changes every time I click on `button1` and so on. Let's suppose that I click on `button4` and `v4` changes to true. How do I check if at least one of the 5 variables is true. Something like this:

```
if(1/5 variables is true) {do something}
```

Should I create an array or something?

Comment: `v1 || v2 || v3 || v4 || v5`

Comment: Put them in an array and run the .some method on it.

Comment: why noot use an array for the values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is conditional `OR` operation:

```
if (v1 || v2 || v3 || v4 || v5) { do something }
```

This is the easiest solution on this regard. But `.some()` is trickier but good way to do also. Check it out.

If it is 100 elements you can't write `(v1 || v2 ...|| v100)` so then using `.some()` will help.

Example:

```js
function isTrue(element, index, array) {
  return element;
}
    
if ([2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isTrue)) { do something; }
```

Comment: @Werl_: check the answer.

Answer (score 14):

```
if([v1, v2, v3, v4, v5].some(item => item)) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method #1:
You can apply **multiple variables** to a single var using commas but if you really need the separation then use that instead.

```
    var v1,v2,v3,v4,v5 = false;

    if (v1 || v2 || v3 || v4 || v5) 
    {
      //code to be executed
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write or condition in your if statement.

```
  if( v1 || v2 || v3 || v4 || v5) 
{ 
// Do something
}
```